# Path length of node_modules) kills jhipster project

Tags: path, jhipster

Creating nice project stubs using jhipster has worked fine until recently.

Now on Windows 7 the node_modules look like deeply recursive folders, deep enough to grab a hole into the FS. As a consequence maven is not capable anymore of building the project.

Can anybody out there help a jhipster newbie?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the path length is limited on Windows. You could try to generate your project at the root of your hard drive, that should give you more chances to make it work -> other people have it working on Windows, so it should be OK